# selector - insertBefore()

Tags: jquery

how can you use insertBefore() when you don't have the id, class or anything for the table but only the object?

```
var tbl_elm = $('the table');

$('<tr><td>txt</td></tr>').insertBefore(tbl_elm.eq(0));
```

somehow I need to tell the eq() that the index has to be found in a 'TR' tag

Comment: I don't believe that you *can,* legitimately, insert a `tr` before/outside of a `table`. But surely you could use `$('<tr><td>txt</td></tr>').appendTo(tbl_elm);`

Comment: Can you elaborate on "tell the eq() that the index has to be found in a 'TR' tag?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var tbl_elm = $("TABLE");    
$('<tr><td>txt</td></tr>').insertBefore($("TR", tbl_elm).eq(0))
```

However, if the elements you are adding to the table will always be placed before the first row, the below code is better practice:

```
var tbl_elm = $("TABLE");
$('<tr><td>txt</td></tr>').prependTo(tbl_elm)
```

Comment: it doesnt work.. $('<tr><td>'+data[i].name+'</td></tr>').insertBefore($('TR', this.scope.list).eq(index)); it looks like it adds the DOM elements directly on body or something